# How to figure out from where the user comes to the page

Tags: ajax, playframework, playframework-2.0

I need to figure out from what page request was made. For example, a user on a page A via AJAX call or a link calls the API or page B.

Would it be possible to figure out from which page the user comes to the page B in PlayFramework 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Referer` header just like (Java):

```
String referer = request().getHeader("REFERER");
```

which gives you whole URL of the referring page.

Of course you shouldn't use it i.e. for authentication in any case as it's easy to override it.